# Use javascript variable in html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

```html
<form action="/key" method="POST">
  <label>key_1:</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="a" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" required/><br />
  <label>key_2: </label><br />
  <input type="text" name="b" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" required/><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="REQUEST" />
</form>
```

```js
var socket = io.connect();
jQuery(function($) {
  var aCounter = $('li.a'),
    bCounter = $('li.b'),
    aCounterPercentage = $('li.a span'),
    bCounterPercentage = $('li.b span'),
    aList = $('#a ul'),
    bList = $('#b ul');
  socket.on('percentages', function(data) {
    aCounter
      .css("width", data.a + '%');
    aCounterPercentage
      .text(Math.round(data.a * 10) / 10 + '%');
    bCounter
      .css("width", data.b + '%');
    bCounterPercentage
      .text(Math.round(data.b * 10) / 10 + '%');
  });
  socket.on('a', function(data) {
    $('<img />')
      .attr('src', data.avatar)
      .load(function() {
        aList
          .prepend($('<li>')
            .prepend($('<p>').text(data.user + ': ' + data.text))
            .prepend($(this)));
      });
  });
  socket.on('b', function(data) {
    $('<img />')
      .attr('src', data.avatar)
      .load(function() {
        bList
          .prepend($('<li>')
            .prepend($('<p>').text(data.user + ': ' + data.text))
            .prepend($(this)));
      });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

ul.percentage {
  width: 100%;
  float: left
}

ul.percentage li {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  clear: left
}

ul.percentage li.a {
  background: #ff0066;
  color: #fff
}

ul.percentage li.b {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff
}

ul.percentage li span {
  float: right;
  display: block
}

ul.tweets {
  float: left;
  clear: both
}

#stream {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%
}

#stream ul {
  list-style: none
}

#stream ul li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  : 5px;
  padding: 5px 0
}

#stream ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f5f6;
}

#stream ul li img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 5px
}

#a {
  width: 45%;
  float: left
}

#b {
  width: 45%;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<h1>GRAPH BASED ON THE KEYWORD</h1>
<ul class="percentage">
  <li class="a">
    a
    <span>0</span>
  </li>
  <li class="b">
    b
    <span>0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<section id="stream">
  <section id="a">
    <h2>tweets of A</h2>
    <ul></ul>
  </section>
  <section id="b">
    <h2>tweets of B</h2>
    <ul></ul>
  </section>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

this is  my code   i am going to fetch the a and b value and will be assigned what i will give in my from.html input box can anybody  help me how i have to  do it. that variable should display in my ul and li class .

Comment: Please take the time to write complete, distinct sentences with proper capitalization and punctuation. What you have there now is frankly near-unreadable.

Comment: I agree, if you'd like people to help you, the least you can do for them is to take a bit of time and write properly. Just a question of respect.

Comment: hey, please correct me if Im wrong. You are trying to put a value on your list according to the users input? Where are your input box?

Comment: suppose if give a= hello and b=hi in my input box  it should assign the value what  i given.

Comment: @MISY What input box?? Certainly you're missing some code here...can you include the rest of your code? So we can help you properly

Answer (score 0):

If you have some inputs let's say

```
<input type="text" id="inputA" name="inputA">
<input type="text" id="inputB" name="inputB">
```

and then you want to introduce the values in the list, I would recommend use some ids and classes.

```
<ul id="ab_list" class="percentage">
      <li id="li_a">
        <span class="val">a</span>
        <span class="per">0</span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_b">
        <span class="val">b</span>
        <span class="per">0</span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

So you can then easily use **jQuery** to do

```
<script>
  var data_a = $("#inputA").val();
  var data_b = $("#inputB").val();
  $("#ab_list #li_a .val").html(data_a);
  $("#ab_list #li_b .val").html(data_b);
<script>
```

Here you have an initial **jsfiddle** from where you can continue with your research/work http://jsfiddle.net/pfkx2nm7/. Of course you would need some kind of event (button click, key enter, form submit...etc) to submit your changes in the input box.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: this code did not worked me .  i edited the code  before i posted .  please see the code .

Comment: can anybody guide me how i have to do it.